# Nonlinear PCA‏ ( R package homals)

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, nonlinear

I'm using the NLPCA to reduce the dimensionality of nine variables (4 nominal / 3 ordinal /2 numeric) to obtain the object-scores to be used as dependent variable in a regression model.
I'm using the package homals (http://www.jstatsoft.org/v31/i04/paper).

The output is:

```
X <- homals(sintomi[,2:10], ndim = 1, active = TRUE, level = c("numerical", rep("ordinal",3),"numerical",rep("ordinal",4)))

X
Call: homals(data = sintomi[, 2:10], ndim = 1, level = c("numerical", 
    rep("ordinal", 3), "numerical", rep("ordinal", 4)), active = TRUE)

Loss: 0.0002077596 

Eigenvalues:
    D1 
0.0208 

Variable Loadings:
           D1
V1  0.2096132
V2  0.2420691
V3  0.2171551
V4  0.1370880
V5  0.1508221
V6  0.2537438
V7  0.1959783
V8  0.1769447
V12 0.2154044


predict(X)

Classification rate:
  Variable Cl. Rate %Cl. Rate

1       V1   0.5149     51.49 
2       V2   0.7292     72.92 
3       V3   0.7589     75.89 
4       V4   0.7768     77.68 
5       V5   0.6336     63.36 
6       V6   0.9048     90.48 
7       V7   0.8869     88.69 
8       V8   0.8036     80.36 
9      V12   0.8661     86.61
```

I'm having the following questions:

1. Is it best to consider Ndim = rank = 1 or Ndim = rank = max
   (rank)  to reduce the dimensionality of data in one component?
2. Is there a command to automatically calculate the proportion of
   variance explained by the first component? Otherwise, how can I
   calculate it by hand?
3. Is it necessary to standardize numeric variables before perfoming "homals"?

If anyone has any thoughts for this, responses would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.